# Vertical menu Navigation - Sub menu is not displaying when Menu has scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, menu, hover

In Vertical Menu, While menu hovering It will display the submenu. When there are more number of Menus it will have scroll.

**Issue**

I can't move to the Submenu when Menu has scroll. But I can see the Submenu.

[image]

**Fiddle**

I have   [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeysinghanbu/6fg4rafc/9/)

```
#magik-verticalmenu .verticalmenu.navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a negative margin to your submenu and it will be over the scrollbar

```
#magik-verticalmenu .verticalmenu.navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  margin-left:-20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6fg4rafc/10/

Comment: Thanks for the solution. By this solution user can't see how longer scroll will be. Can we show the submenu even with scroll and same position

Comment: The problem is that when the user hover the scroll bar, he is not hovering the menu item anymore, that's why the submenu disapear. But even with my solution, the user can see the scrollbar when the submenu is not displayed so he should know he can scroll. Currently i have no other solution, I hope it will help you to find a better one in any way ;)